# Can Apps targeting an older version use newer libraries?

Tags: android, android-library, target

For example I have an app targeting 25 support libraries.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.streethawk.pointzireact"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
```

Then I want to add a third party library using newest 27 features on Android 8. So this third party library include android.support.version 27.1.1

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.notificationbuilder:1.9.25'    

}
```

Do i have to increase my App from 25 to 27 in order to include this library ?

Comment: You have to update your targetSdkVersion to 26 or above otherwise you can not upload your APK on play store read [this](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk) announcement

Comment: @RutvikBhatt thanks, but this is just an internal app, not for uploading on Google play. But question can Apps targeting older versions user newer libraries?

Comment: you can use it but it may be the conflict

Comment: so what would be a good solution?

Comment: Update the versions

Comment: how do I  get the app to use the third party library's support version instead of the apps?

Comment: `how do I get the app to use` that is totally defferent question. Don't ask questions in comments. If you have a **new question** then ask a **new question**